# Javascript single quote inside string for exported text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, readme

I am creating a node.js file that creates and readme file where the install directions need to be displayed as shell or javascript type font.  However, I have not been able to use the single quotes required to make that work since they close out the string.

````
function generateExport(data) {
  const { username, ...title} = data;

  return `
    ```shell <--- how would you do this ?
    ${data.title} 
    ```  <----- and this?
`;
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the string with a backslash before each one

```js
function generateExport(data) {
  const { username, ...title} = data;

  return `
    \`\`\`shell <--- how would you do this ?
    ${data.title} 
    \`\`\`  <----- and this?
`;
}
```